# Adding padding and border radius in background text in Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, fabricjs

Is there any chance to add padding and border radius on Fabric JS background text i want to look like call to action button

[image]

**JS**

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mainCanvas',
    backgroundColor: 'green'
)


text = new fabric.IText('hello world', 
    left: 200
    top: 100
    backgroundColor: "pink",
)
canvas.add(text)
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="mainCanvas" style="border:1px solid #aaa" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/edinpuzic/GZJbZ/8/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply grouping the elements and in `fabric.Rect` I added  `rx: 5` and `ry: 5` for border radius.

There is all the code [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/edinpuzic/fgWNL/177/)

```js
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');




var bg = new fabric.Rect({
  fill: '#32b775',
  scaleY: 0.5,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  rx: 5, 
  ry: 5,
  width: 90,
  height:80
});

var text = new fabric.Text('Done', {
  fontSize: 18,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  fill: '#FFF'
});

var group = new fabric.Group([ bg, text ], {
  left: 50,
  top: 100
});

canvas.add(group);
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="c1" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a solution with `Textbox`,

Here's another solution you can try: https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/3731

```
var TextboxWithPadding = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox, {
  _renderBackground: function(ctx) {
    if (!this.backgroundColor) {
      return;
    }
    var dim = this._getNonTransformedDimensions();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.backgroundColor;

    ctx.fillRect(
      -dim.x / 2 - this.padding,
      -dim.y / 2 - this.padding,
      dim.x + this.padding * 2,
      dim.y + this.padding * 2
    );
    // if there is background color no other shadows
    // should be casted
    this._removeShadow(ctx);
  }
});
```

Extend the base class and overwrite the `_renderBackground` function.

Very simple and works well for me!

Comment: The background is incorrectly rendered if you scale the Textbox in height.